# Javascript Objects and the this keyword

Tags: javascript, class, object, this

I know that *this* references to the object owner. But I'm having a hard time trying to make a class work, while trying to identify what *this* is referencing to.

Guess it's best to just show the code:

```
function Ajax_Class(params) {
// Public Properties
this.Response = null;

// Private Properties
var RequestObj = null;

// Prototype Methods
this.OnReset    = function() { };
this.OnOpenConn = function() { };
this.OnDataSent = function() { };
this.OnLoading  = function() { };
this.OnSuccess  = function() { alert("default onSuccess method."); };
this.OnFailure  = function() { alert("default onFailure method."); };

// Public Methods
this.Close = function() {   // Abort current Request
    if (RequestObj) {
        RequestObj.abort();
        RequestObj = null;
        return true;
    } else return false;
};

// Private Methods
var Instance = function() {     // To create instance of Http Request
    try { return new XMLHttpRequest(); }
    catch (error) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
    catch (error) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
    catch (error) {}

    // throw new Error("Could not create HTTP request object.");
    return false;
};

var ReadyStateHandler = function() {
    // Switch through possible results
    switch(RequestObj.readyState) {
        case 0:
            this.OnReset();
        break;

        case 1:
            this.OnOpenConn();
        break;

        case 2:
            this.OnDataSent();
        break;

        case 3:
            this.OnLoading();
        break;

        case 4:
            // Check Status
            if (RequestObj.status == 200)  {
                // Handle Response
                Response = HandleResponse();
                // Call On Success
                this.OnSuccess();
                // Hide Loading Div
                LoadingDiv(true);
            } else {
                this.OnFailure();
            }

        break;
    } // End Switch
};

var Open = function() {
    // In case it's XML, Override the Mime Type
    if ((params["ResponseType"] == "XML") && (RequestObj.overrideMimeType)) 
        RequestObj.overrideMimeType('text/xml');

    // 
    if ((params["User"]) && (params["Password"]))
        RequestObj.open(params["Method"], params["URL"],  params["Async"], params["User"], params["Password"]);
    else if (params["User"])
        RequestObj.open(params["Method"], params["URL"],  params["Async"], params["User"]);
    else
        RequestObj.open(params["Method"], params["URL"],  params["Async"]);

    // Set Request Header ?
    if (params["method"] == "POST") 
        //this.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        RequestObj.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

};

var Send = function() {
    if (params["Data"])     RequestObj.send(params["Data"]);
    else                    RequestObj.send(null);
};

var HandleResponse = function() {
    if (params["ResponseType"] == "JSON")
        return ParseJSON(RequestObj.responseText);
    else if (params["ResponseType"] == "XML")
        return RequestObj.responseXML;
    else 
        return RequestObj.responseText;
};

// Method ParseJSON
var ParseJSON = function(obj) {
    if (obj)
        return JSON.parse(obj);
}; // End ParseJSON

// Method LoadingDiv -> Either Shows or Hides the Loading Div
var LoadingDiv = function(hide) {
    // Hide the Modal Window
    if (hide) { document.getElementById("Async").style.display = "none"; return false; }

    // Show Modal Window
    document.getElementById("Async").style.display = "block";

    // Reset the Position of the Modal_Content to 0, x and y
    document.getElementById("Async_Container").style.left = "0px";
    document.getElementById("Async_Container").style.top = "0px";

    // Center the Modal Area, no matter what the content
    var Screen_Width, Screen_Height;
        // Get screen data
        if (typeof(window.innerWidth) == "number") { Screen_Width = window.innerWidth; Screen_Height = window.innerHeight; }            //Non-IE
        else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {         //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
            Screen_Width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            Screen_Height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        } else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {                                        //IE 4 compatible
            Screen_Width = document.body.clientWidth;
            Screen_Height = document.body.clientHeight;
        }

        // Set Modal_Content Max Height to allow overflow
        document.getElementById("Async_Container").style.maxHeight = Screen_Height - 200 + "px";

        // Get Modal_Container data
        var El_Width = document.getElementById("Async_Container").offsetWidth;
        var El_Height = document.getElementById("Async_Container").offsetHeight;


    // Set the Position of the Modal_Content
    document.getElementById("Async_Container").style.left = ((Screen_Width/2) - (El_Width/2)) + "px";
    document.getElementById("Async_Container").style.top = ((Screen_Height/2) - (El_Height/2)) + "px";
};


// Constructor

// Check the Params
// Required Params
if (!params["URL"]) return false;
// Default Params
params["Method"]        = (!params["Method"]) ? "GET" : params["Method"];   // GET, POST, PUT, PROPFIND
params["Async"]         = (params["Async"] === false) ? false : true;
params["ResponseType"]  = (!params["ResponseType"]) ? "JSON" : params["ResponseType"];  // JSON, TXT, XML
params["Loading"]       = (params["Loading"] === false) ? false : true;
// Optional Params
// params["User"])
// params["Password"]

// Create Instance of Http Request Object
RequestObj = Instance();

// Handle Ajax according to Async
if (params["Async"]) {
    // Handle what should be done in case readyState changes
    if (params["Loading"]) LoadingDiv();
    // State Handler || Response is Handled within the code
    RequestObj.onreadystatechange = ReadyStateHandler;
    // Open & Send
    Open();
    Send();
} else {
    // Handle the Loading Div
    if (params["Loading"]) LoadingDiv();
    // Open & Send
    Open();
    Send();
    // Handle Response
    this.Response = HandleResponse();
    // No State Handler, Application has been waiting for modifications.
    //this.OnSuccess(Response);
    // Handle the Loading Div
    LoadingDiv(true);
}

// no problems?
return true;

} // End Ajax
```

Then, inside the page:

```
window.onload = function() {

update_states = function() {
    this.OnSuccess = function() {
        alert("overriden onSuccess Method");
    };
};
    update_states.prototype = new Ajax_Class({URL:"ajax/states.php?id=5&seed="+Math.random()});
    run_update_states = new update_states;      

} // Window Onload
```

What I'm trying to do is have a Default OnSuccess (and etc.) Method, and, in case there's need, I can override the default methods with the subclass method, but it will still be called automatically upon HttpRequest state change.

I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction, and would be amazed if I could ever understand why *this* isn't working in this circunstance and how to make it reference to the correct object.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `console.log(this)` in Firefox or Chrome helps out in determining what `this` refers to in a certain part of your code (scope). Also, `this` isn't the object owner, its the object itself. Another handy tip is using `typeof(this)` or `this.constructor` to get more info on the object.

Comment: I see. The way it is, this.OnSuccess if pointing to the object xmlHttpRequest. Makes sense, based on what you say. But when I tried, while on the Class block, something like: var self = this; then I couldn't override the Class Methods, because it would always be referring to the main class. Does that make any sense?

Comment: I did what Jfriend00 said:
function Ajax_Class() {
var self = this;
 (...)
then tried, on state change:
self.OnSuccess();

then it will always call the default class OnSuccess function, not the one I set on the subclass...

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. For prototyping and scope resolution, try this  [resource](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clResO). "The Resolution of Property Names on Objects" section.

Comment: @MalSu—`this` has nothing to do with scope, they are completely different things. In ES5 strict mode, `this` can be anything, even `undefined` or `null`. Kudos though for referencing Richard Cornford.

Comment: @IgorDonin—it would help if you reduce your code to the minimum that displays the issue. It isn't clear to me which `this` you are referring to. As jfriend00 said, `this` in an AJAX callback is not the same as calling function's `this` unless you make it so.

Comment: @IgorDonin I still can't pinpoint your problem, mate.

Comment: I think something that can make this easier is to change your onSuccess/onFailure methods to handle callbacks, instead of method overloading.

Comment: Mind the final run_update_state instance. That this.OnSuccess is supposed to be called, raising an alert("overriden onSuccess Method") instead of the default alert("default onSuccess method"). I tried to replace this.OnSuccess for self.OnSuccess on the Ajax_Class (case 4), but when I do that, then update_state method which was supposed to override the default one, never gets called - all I get is "default onSuccess method".

Comment: @leemachin Yes, I have considered that possibility... If I can't solve the problem, I will use a callback function.

Comment: @IgorDonin note that it's also more idiomatic. If no callback is supplied, revert to a default. `(success || this.onSuccess).call(this)`

Comment: I just found something similar, but I can't see the difference from what I'm doing: http://www.bytemycode.com/snippets/snippet/329/

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help. Chosen jfriend00 answer's because understanding how *this* works gets me closer to a solution.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is set according to how something is called.  These are the different ways it is set:

1. `func()` - A normal function call.  `this` is set to the global object (`window` in a browser) .
2. `obj.method()` - A method call.  `this` is set to `obj`.
3. `func.call(obj, arg1, arg2, ...)` - using `.call()`.  `this` is set to `obj`.
4. `func.apply(obj, args)` - using `.apply()`.  `this` is set to `obj`.
5. `func.bind(obj, arg1, arg2, ...)` - using `.bind()`.  Creates a new function that sets `this` to `obj` when called (internally, it uses `.apply()` in its implementation).

Typical things to watch out for.

- Calling a regular function, even from within an object's method will cause the `this` pointer to be `window` inside that function.
- A callback function will typically receive a different `this` value than the code it might be embedded in.  You may have to save the original `this` value into a local variable (often called `self` by convention) so you can refer to it from your callback function.

Comment: note that `call`, `apply`, and, more recently, `bind`, can all change the context of `this` to whatever you want, the latter doing so without executing the function.

Comment: @leemachin - I added `.bind()` - already had `.call()` and `.apply()`.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But this is confusing me, actually. So what's the expected behavior of this when I create a new instance of an object?

Comment: @IgorDonin - Your question only has 1/3 the information needed to answer.  If you create a new object called `myObject` and call a method on that object with `myObject.print()`, then `this` will be set to `myObject` inside the `print()` method for that specific call.  If you have a different object `yourObject` and you call `yourObject.print()`, then `this` will be set to `yourObject` inside that specific execution of the `print` method.  It is the caller that determines how `this` is set.

Comment: My question has the entire class and the objects instantiation. It's all there, mate. update_state is a class that uses Ajax_Class as a prototype and has a OnSuccess method that overrides the prototype's. run_update_state creates an instance of update_state, which gets a response of a http request and handles it. What I want is the method OnSuccess of the update_state to be run instead of the prototype's method.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are trying to do something like:

```
function Base() {}

Base.prototype.showName = function() {
  alert('Base method: ' + this.name);
}

function Foo(name, arg){

   this.name = name;

  // Extend this if arg is an object
  if (typeof arg == 'object') {
    for (var p in arg) {

      // This references the new instance if called with new keyword
      if (arg.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        this[p] = arg[p];
      }
    }
  }
}

Foo.prototype = new Base();

// Re-assign constructor property (not very useful but some to do like this)
Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo; 

var inst0 = new Foo('foo 0');

// Override inherited method
var inst1 = new Foo(
             'foo 1',
             {showName: function(){alert('Instance method: ' + this.name);}}
            );

inst0.showName(); // Base method: foo 0
inst1.showName(); // Instance method: foo 1
```

But there are other (simpler? better?) ways of doing that. Make prototype inheritance and javascript's dynamic nature work for you, don't try to make it emulate other inheritance patterns just because you're more comfortable with them.

Comment: It took me a while to see the wisdom in your answer. Cheers, mate.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

```
run_update_states = new update_states();
```

notice the parentheses.

Comment: thanks for your answer, mate. I tested it, but no go. What's the expected result when you create an instance of an object and run a function at the same time? Does the object run_update_states get created?

Comment: if this is not a problem to you script, you can pass the function that you need `onSuccesss` as a parameter to the `AjaxClass` and add it to the object if it exists.